# Kettle transformation with muli input streams

Tags: kettle

I have two files with single fields. It looks like:

```
File A          File B
a1              b1
a2              b2
a3              b3
a4              b4
```

I would like to have a1,b1; a2,b2 but when I connect two inputs into transformation Kettle says that inputs have different layouts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have any details of your transformation, but I guess you picked the 'Append streams' step. You should use the Merge Join step and two 'Add sequence' step to add a line nr to the input (set a different counter name for both steps). Connect your two 'Add sequence' steps to this 'Merge Join' step configure the key fields as line number and set the join type to: 'FULL OUTER'. Next you can use a Select values step to get rid of the line number columns.

Comment: Works great :-). FULL OUTER generates n-1 record from one input stream, so I used INNER and everything looks great. Thanks for help :)